# EC2 to RDS timeout issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to connect to an RDS database from an instance. Unfortunately the connection times out instead of succeeding. I checked the usual suspects, and can't find a reason why it happens. Here are the details for more context:

- both the instance and RDS live in the same VPC
- RDS is in a subnet in `us-east-1e`, instance is in `us-east-1a`
- instance has allow-all outbound security group
- RDS has allow-all inbound security group
- VPC has `172.31.0.0/16` assigned with routing table directing `172.31.0.0/16` to local
- same VPC network ACL is assigned to all subnets and allows all traffic
- instance is on `172.31.25.31` and can resolve the RDS endpoint to `172.31.48.16`
- instance has connection to the internet, so general networking is ok
- lambda functions can connect to this RDS, so general networking on that side is also ok

What else did I miss? How can I debug this further?

Comment: How are you trying to connect to the RDS instance? Have you allowed the relevant subnets to access the RDS instance? have you set the correct subnet group?

Comment: Perhaps you should add the many screenshots that show what you've set up, so we can validate what you've said above. Also, why RDS in a different AZ? That means you pay for the network traffic.

Comment: @ItaiGanot Trying any TCP connection. nc for example. I'm not sure what you mean by allowed access: security groups, nacl, routing is set up as described - is there something specific you mean? The subnet group allowed the db to spawn in the same VPC as the instance, so I'll go with yes.

Comment: @Tim I'm happy to add information you ask for. Screenshots will not make this more readable, just longer :-) RDS is supposed to be reachable from all AZs in this VPC for high availability purposes.

Comment: If no-one can answer the question with the information provided perhaps then do the screenshots.